# I plan to set DB server with MHA setting,I need advice about the structure of DB

Tags: mariadb

I run Maria DB server on Ubuntu 20.04 now,I connected NAS to one schema of the DB.

Now I want to run another DB server for backup and do role of Original server when emergency occured.

I setup one monitor server for installing MHA manager, and I finished installed it.

I setted replication user for keepping replicate to second DB when change occured to original DB.

The simuration are this

1. Original DB are down
2. Monitor server find out it
3. Second DB are take over the role of Original DB
4. Administrator fix the problem
5. Original DB receive the missing data during down
6. Original DB take the role from Second DB

Is is reasonable? or please give me good advice for it

Thank you for reading

Comment: I would recommend maxscale instead of MHA. As maxscale is also product of mariadb and have better compatible.

Comment: As per 4th Step, no manual effort required, Auto fail over can be handled by MHA or maxscale itself.